# Make AVPlayerViewController keep playing after done button pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an instance of `AVPlayerViewController` playing a live broadcast content that I am adding as a subview to my viewController's view.

After switching the `AVPlayerViewController` to fullscreen mode and tapping Done button to exit fullscreen the player stops playing.

Is there any way to keep the player playing after done button action?

Comment: probably, you can't detect when done button has been tapped

Comment: Done button is default behavior of AVPlayerViewController. so that will stop player. Please update your post with your code. so anyone can look  into it and help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with `AVPlayerViewController`. But when using fullscreen button the player keeps playing. For my case I ended up by creating a custom player controller with an `AVPlayer` instance.